# Javascript function delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, timer

I make a litle javascript. Like this:

```
content.css('height', contentHeight, function() {
    alert("test");
     $("body").scrollTo("#main", 600);
});
```

I would like the alert is executed, after set the content height. But what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.css()` function is instantanious.

```
content.css('height', contentHeight);
alert("test");
$("body").scrollTo("#main", 600);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no *'done'* handler for such methods like `css()`. It executes immediately.

So you have to write the code as follows:

```
content.css("height", contentHeight);
alert("test");
$("body").scrollTo("#main", 600);
```

However, if you need to add some delay after setting the height, you may use `setTimeout()`:

```
content.css("height", contentHeight);
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("test");
    $("body").scrollTo("#main", 600);
}, 1000);   // 1000 is number of milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The function in jquery css method means different:

```
content.css('height', function(){
    return contentHeight;
});
```

Content is an array, code above sets height for all elements in this array. The usage of this function may be like this:

```
content.css('height', function(index){
    return index * contentHeight;
});
```

In this case height of each next element will increment by contentHeight value.

Answer (score 0):

Using animate, the callback is called when finished.

```
content.animate({
    height: contentHeight
}, 0, function() {
    alert("test");
    $("body").scrollTo("#main", 600);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
content.animate(
    {height : 100}, 
    5000,
    function() {
        //Animation complete.
        alert("test");
        $("body").scrollTo("#main", 600);
    }
);
```